# installing Ubuntu on Lenovo yoga 2 13"

Tags: system-installation, lenovo

Will it be safe to install bionic beaver LTS on my Lenovo yoga 2 13"?

I read that some lenovo laptops had problems regarding the BIOS drivers.

I am new to the world of Ubuntu and by no means an expert in computing, so I apologize if this a bit of a dumb question.

looking forward to switching after borrowing a ubuntu laptop. the gimp is the program I use mostly and that works more then fine on Linux.

Comment: The French Community of Ubuntu Users has a long list of Lenovo laptops (including Yoga series) tested with different versions of Ubuntu that includes test results. 

[List of Lenovo Laptops](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fdoc.ubuntu-fr.org%2Fliste_portables_lenovo&edit-text=&act=url) (Through Google Translate) also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu